# mongodb:how to add one field to the _id index composed of a Compound index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

**I can't remove the _id index, why?**

When I try running the `dropIndexes` command, it removes all indexes but not the _id index.

Doing `'db.runCommand'` doesn't work either:

```
> db.runCommand({dropIndexes:'fs_files',index:{_id:1}})
{ "nIndexesWas" : 2, "errmsg" : "may not delete _id index", "ok" : 0 }
```

not ok.

**Can i use a field including _id in a composite index?**

I couldn't find anything online, the `ensureindex` command can't do it.

> db.fs_files.ensureIndex({'_id':1, 'created':1});

the above command just created a new composite index. i haven't found some similar 'create Index' command.

**the default _id index is a unique index?**

the `getIndexes` returns it's not a unique index.

```
{
     "v" : 1,
     "key" : {
             "_id" : 1
     },
     "ns" : "gridfs.fs_files",
     "name" : "_id_"
 },
 {
     "v" : 1,
     "key" : {
             "created" : 1
     },
     "unique" : true,
     "ns" : "gridfs.fs_files",
     "name" : "created_1"
 }
```

Comment: As Tyler said you can't drop an index _id. But you can create a compound index which includes _id. - And yes _id is the default unique index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete the index on "_id" in mongodb.

Please see the documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-The%5CidIndex)

Answer (score 4):

There is a `createIndex` command in addition to `ensureIndex` also.

E.g.

```
db.<coll>.createIndex({foo:1})
```

Comment: so,i cannot create the compound index for the _id index?

Comment: You can create compound indexes with _id.
`createIndex()` is actually called inside `ensureIndex()` to add the index to the collection. The difference is that `ensureIndex()` calls `getLastError` to make sure there was no error during the index creation. So it's best to use `ensureIndex()`